# Google Sheets: Copy specific row from sheetA to sheetB

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to create a script in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script.

I have 2 Sheets/ Tabs inside the file/project:
-Sheet 'Data' contains a list of Items( 1 item for each row ).
-Sheet 'DataExtraxted' is empty.

I want the code to copy a random row from 'Data' and paste it in 'DataExtracted'.

Im not very good at scripting but i managed to get this code, but the problem is it copys everything from 'Data' onto 'DataExtracted'. I cant seem to change this behaviour even how much i try:

```
function RandomPlant() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Data");
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("DataExtracted");

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();

  sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1,1));
}
```

`
How can i, in Google Shees using Google App Script, create a function that copys a specific row from one Tab and pasts it onto another?